# Unable to install Xcode 4.3.3 in lion 10.7.4

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, xcode4.3

I have downloaded xcode 4.3.3 from Apple Site.

I am not able to install xcode 4.3.3 on MAC OS X Lion 10.7.4. I have searched this site to get the answer and none seems to work.

I have dual boot Leopard and Lion OS in my mac mini. There is no xcode.app in Applications to delete it.
I tried launchpad also and there is no xcode.app

I have xcode 3.1.4 in Leopard. Is it causing any trouble to install this??

Comment: You can install xcode from the App store, have you tried that?

Comment: Can you give us more details about what happend when you tried to install it? Errors etc

Comment: @ZippyV: When I tried to install from App store, it says "This apple ID has not yet been used with iTuneStore" and then asking Credit Card details. Why its asking for the payment details?

Comment: Same problem. What to install xcode which is free but starts crapping on about iTunes and wants my credit card details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you download the .dmg from the Apple Developer Downloads site you simply need to mount the image (double click in Finder) and drag the application into either /Applications or ~/Applications.

It should then appear in LaunchPad, or you can go to the folder you dragged the App to and start it from there.  Then click on its Dock icon and select Options and tell it to stay in the dock.

Then unmount the .dmg (it appears in the left-hand pane of Finder).

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe. Actually what happened is, After I have mounted the image I double clicked on the xcode app instead of dragging in to the Applications folder. Now, It has been installed.